# How to detect system timer going off in iOS

Tags: ios, audio

When the system timer goes off (after a user sets a timer), it automatically pauses the audio in my app. However, I need to listen for the notification in order to have the UI reflect this pause. What do I listen in for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to listen for the `AVAudioSessionInterruptionNotification`[(documentation)](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioSession_ClassReference/index.html#//apple_ref/c/data/AVAudioSessionInterruptionNotification) or if you're using `AVAudioPlayer` you have to implement the delegate method `audioPlayerBeginInterruption:` [(documentation)](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Audio/Conceptual/AudioSessionProgrammingGuide/HandlingAudioInterruptions/HandlingAudioInterruptions.html)